# ScreenState Trouble XNA 4 C#

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm having troubles making it where the SplashScreen switches to the PLaying State. I declare a enum of game states in Game1.cs

```
public enum GameState { SplashScreen, Playing }
public GameState currentState;
```

Then I have this in the LoadContent in Game1.cs

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    splashScreen.LoadContent(Content);
    playState.LoadContent(Content);
}
```

In Update in Game1.cs

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    switch (currentState)
    {
        case GameState.SplashScreen:
        {
            splashScreen.Update(gameTime);
            break;
        }
        case GameState.Playing:
        {
            playState.Update(gameTime);
            break;
        }
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Finally in Game1.cs I have my draw

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    spriteBatch.Begin();

    switch (currentState)
    {
        case GameState.SplashScreen:
        {
            splashScreen.Draw(spriteBatch);
            break;
        }
        case GameState.Playing:
        {
            playState.Draw(spriteBatch) ;
            break;
        }
    }

    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Here's my SplashScreen.cs

```
public class SplashScreen
{
    Texture2D tSplash;
    Vector2 vSplash = Vector2.Zero;

    Game1 main = new Game1();

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        tSplash = Content.Load<Texture2D>("splash");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.X))
        {
            main.currentState = Game1.GameState.Playing;
        }

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(tSplash, vSplash, Color.White);
    }
}
```

And my Playing.cs

```
class Playing
{
    Texture2D tBack;
    Vector2 vBack = Vector2.Zero;

    Game1 mainG = new Game1();

    public void Initialize()
    {
    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager contentManager)
    {
        tBack = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("playing");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(tBack, vBack, Color.White);
    }
}
```

The SplashScreen image shows up but when I press X the PlatyingState doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a brand new `Game` object for each screen. Never do this. One `Game` is meant to represent your entire game.

However, it is okay to have multiple *references* to one single `Game` object.

Keep one single `Game` object at the topmost level; you already have it holding your screen objects. You can even keep the `main` and `mainG` variables in your screens, but make them instead point to your single `Game`:

```
public class SplashScreen
{
    Game1 main;
    public SplashScreen(Game1 g)
    {
        main = g;
    }

    //rest can be largely the same
}
```

Do basically the same for Playing (take in a `Game1` and set the reference rather than declaring anew).

Then in Game1.cs:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    splashScreen = new SplashScreen(this);
    splashScreen.LoadContent(Content);
    playState = new Playing(this);
    playState.LoadContent(Content);
}
```

This will be a good first step, although I recommend taking this further and creating a base class for all your screens. Check out the [official XNA sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) for game screen management to get you going.